# Keep a J2EE web application working offline

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, synchronization, offline-mode

I am student and I need to develop J2EE web application, that allows the user to work offline and also allows to perform CRUD operations, and once the server is turned on, the data that has been modified must be synchronized with the data already stored in the database.

So there's some framework that can do this ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you mean a user, with a browser, should be able to connect to a server that has been turned off? Because surely, that's the definition of *not* J2EE. The only alternative will be some lightweight client side work that will be possible with only HTML5 and dependent on the browser's support for such work. For further reading http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html

Comment: Thank you for the link, so ! i can work with HTML5 and localStorage in my jsp pages ? and retrieve the modified data, once the server is turned on ? is that possible ?